# Java Type Erasure: Rules of cast insertion?

Tags: java, generics, casting, erasure

The Java [tutorial on type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) doesn't seem to detail the specific rules of cast insertion by the compiler.  Can someone please explain the specific rules that cause the transformation detailed by the tutorial (reproduced below):

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}
public class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}

MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
Node n = (MyNode)mn;         // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
n.setData("Hello");
Integer x = (String)mn.data; // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
```

Specifically, I'm wondering what rules cause the insertion of `(MyNode)` and `(String)`.  When is a cast inserted, and how is the type chosen for the cast?

Comment: Compiler does not insert casts. You, as programmer, should insert casts if required and compiler will check whether they are correct or not.

Comment: That is not true, it will add casts behind the scenes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. **`MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);`**

   - will create an instance of `MyNode` which defines the generic type `T` of interface `Node` as `Integer`
   - casting: no casting necessary by developer, no casts added by compiler
2. **`Node n = (MyNode)mn;`**

   - this will basically tell the compiler forget about the generic type `T` and use the interface `Node` completely without generics which will have the following consequence: **imagine generic type `T` to be treated as `java.lang.Object`**
   - casting: no casting necessary by developer, no casts added by compiler
3. **`n.setData("Hello");`**

   - **will allow you to add any kind ob object** because T is treated as Object (`String`, `Integer`, array, anything else)
   - casting: no casting necessary by developer, no casts added by compiler
4. **`Integer x = mn.data;`**

   - `nm.data` should return an `Integer` type as `Integer` is defined as generic type argument `T` in the `MyNode` class
   - however because you used raw types which allowed you to add a `String` instead, the **`nm.data` holds a `String` instance**
   - casting: no casting necessary by developer, however the compiler will add casts to Integer behind the scenes for you and because of type mismatch, you will get the `ClassCastException`

Comment: Can you elaborate on specifically *when* casts are inserted?  I think I understand the "why" aspect, but I'm unclear on the set of circumstances in which casts are relevant.

Comment: Added casting explanations.

Comment: Can you explain why you are saying that compiler will  add Integer casting if we see that in code he adds cast for String?
Also it seems that _mn_ is being cast to _MyNode_, why?

Answer (score 3):

The `ClassCastException` would be `throw` when a call is made to

```
n.setData("Hello");
```

This is because the compiler builds bridge methods to preserve polymorphism. The bridge method will look like:

```
 public void setData(Object data) {
       setData((Integer)data);   //the exception is thrown here
  }
```

since an instance of a string cannot be converted to `Integer`, the `ClassCastException` would be thrown.

You can read about bridge methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

Comment: +1. Indeed, I have tested the code myself and the `ClassCastException` should be thrown in this line instead of the next line. The Java Tutorials - "Effects of Type Erasure and Bridge Methods" is wrong about it. Moreover, if you try to decompile the .class file, you should get `Integer x = (Integer)mn.data;` instead. I am using JDK 8, probably this particular tutorials page is not up-to-date although the whole tutorials section about generics is _written for JDK 8_.

Comment: The bridge method added can be observed via javap tool. Execute "javap -c -verbose MyNode.class" and you will see there are 2 methods called setData, one of which is the bridge method. In the tutorial casting information is incorrect as you said. In terms of casts, only casting to Integer is added by the compiler for "Integer x = mn.data" line. The "Node n = mn;" is not extended with a cast because it does not really need any casting.