# Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-erasure

As the official tutorial about [generics type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), and this statement is so confusing me. When the **type cast inserting** might occur exactly? I tried with some simple usages of generics and using `javap -c a.class` to check the bytecode but it seems no typecasting inserted as I expected.

The so-called duplicated is more about the **bridge method** using a type cast to ensure there is proper `polymorphism` while I am wondering what the second statement means exactly.

> Insert type casts if necessary to preserve **type safety.**

Any example could be provided to demonstrate it?

Comment: Can you please post a.java code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Type Erasure: Rules of cast insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587502/java-type-erasure-rules-of-cast-insertion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I think [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339708/2361308) cleared out the confusion.

> when generics are used, they're converted into compile-time checks and **execution-time casts**.

When we try to compile `a.java` and decompile the `a.class`, we will see the magic (compiler helps auto-insert type cast).

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("hell");
    out.println(list.get(0));
```

After being decompiled:

```
    ArrayList var3 = new ArrayList();
    var3.add("hell");
    System.out.println((String)var3.get(0));
```

---

[Using Legacy Code in Generic Code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/legacy.html)  from the official generic tutorial:

> ... whenever the resulting code isn't type-correct, **a cast to the appropriate type is inserted**...