# How java erasure decided which cast to make to return type?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-erasure

i am spending a lot of time on learning Generic feature in Java. I tried to read explanation in the following link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html , and i didn't understand and also tried to understand the issue by the following link from the forum: [Java Type Erasure: Rules of cast insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587502/java-type-erasure-rules-of-cast-insertion), but still things are far a way from being clear for me, and i also added a comment to post but i'm doubt if someone will refer to a comment because the post is very old.

I'm trying to understand how the compiler knows which cast to make for method returned type when he makes the erasure. In the book i'm learning from (Deital - Java How to Program), i think that something in the explanation is missing (maybe a typo). Is is written there: " In each case, the type of the cast for the return value is inferred from the types of the method arguments in the particular method call, because, according to the method declaration,
the return type and the argument types match.
As i understand the sentence, it says that the cast is according to the arguments that were send when the method was called. But if the methods doesn't get any argument. e.g, if the method prototype is:

```
public static <T extends Animal> T funcA ()
```

Now 3 different methods call the function. One wants to get a Dog a returned type (`Dog d = funcA()`), the second one wants to get Cat (`Cat c = funcA()`) and the last one wants to get Animal (`Animal A = funcA()`).
How does erasure decide which cast to make?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't actually have anything to do with erasure. The type is inferred from the *call site*: what type the caller is "actually expecting.  `Animal a = funcA()` is equivalent to `Animal a = MyClass.<Animal>funcA()`, `Dog d = funcA()` is equivalent to `Dog d = MyClass.<Dog>funcA()`.

Whether this works at an *implementation* level does have something to do with erasure, and there isn't actually a valid implementation for `funcA` -- one that won't have compiler warnings, or equivalently, one that won't fail at runtime -- other than (something that boils down to) `return null`.

Comment: *"there isn't actually a valid implementation for `funcA`"* Sure there is, since **erasure** caused the code to be compiled as `Animal funcA()`, any implementation that returns an `Animal` (or a subtype thereof) will do. The question is entirely about erasure, and how the compiler makes it work, e.g. how the compiler uses erasure to make `Dog d = funcA()` compile as (be equivalent to) `Dog d = (Dog) funcA()`.

Comment: Sorry, I read "valid" as "compilable", and I now realize that's probably not what you meant. You're right that there is no implementation that would make all 3 calls run without error, since erasure means that the code in `funcA()` doesn't (cannot) know which type the caller expects. My point still stands though, in that the code will compile, because the compiler added casts, which is what the question is all about.

Comment: If you could clarify what you meant, SO will allow me to remove the down-vote I gave you.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, can you explain the following syntax: '_MyClass.<Animal>funcA()_'?

Comment: `MyClass.<Animal>funcA()` explicitly forces `T` in `public static <T extends Animal> T funcA()` to be `Animal`.  I am assuming `funcA` is a method in the class `MyClass`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, Hi. So you actually say that the cast is determined by left side of the assignment. In my case _Dog d_? Because it's not what is deduced from quotation i have attached (from 'Deitel's book) in my post.   In addition i had some problem to understand your mind when saying _Whether this works at an implementation level does have something to do with erasure_, is there other way to explain that i will have better chance to understand?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am saying.  And as far as erasure goes: functions that "don't get any argument", as you say in your question, and still have a generic return value, can't do much of anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

based on the target types in the following statements

- Dog d = funcA()
- Cat c = funcA()
- Animal A = funcA()

the compiler is using Type Inference (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). If you look at the examples in the Target Types section you will see something similar to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different issues at hand:

- Type erasure of the actual method
- Bridge methods when overriding inherited method
- Casting when calling the method

---

You example is:

```
public static <T extends Animal> T funcA ()
```

That method cannot have anything to do with bridge methods, because it is static.

Type erasure means that the compiler eliminates (erases) the generic type, so the code is compiled as-if you wrote:

```
public static Animal funcA ()
```

Because of that, when you then call the method, casting is added by the compiler:

```
Dog d = (Dog) funcA()
```

As you can see, the compiled code doesn't have generic types, it is all "magic" implemented by the compiler, to pretend that generics actually exist.

---

Now, if you actually were interested in bridge methods and how erasure works, then let's look at the example in the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) you provided.

In that article, the method in the base class is declared as:

```
public class Node<T> {
    public void setData(T data)
```

Erasure compiles that as:

```
public class Node {
    public void setData(Object data)
```

In the subclass the method is declared as:

```
public class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public void setData(Integer data)
```

Erasure compiles that as:

```
public class MyNode extends Node {
    public void setData(Integer data)
```

Now a bridge method is added by the compiler, because the JVM needs an overriding method in the subclass with an `Object` parameter type:

```
@Override
public void setData(Object data) {
    setData((Integer) data);
}
```

As you can see, the compiler once again added a cast. I hope this answers your question about how the compiler knows which cast to make, when it makes the erasure.

Comment: Hi, Some questions since i'm feeling that i can't understand any of the answer i got (my fault) : 1. in the code: _Dog d = (Dog) funcA()_, who added the _Dog_ cast?  2. _"Now a bridge method is added by the compiler, because the JVM needs an overriding method in the subclass with an Object parameter type_", why subclass need to override _setData(Object Data)_ method?

Comment: @Eitanos30 1. Try reading the answer again. The line before `Dog d = (Dog) funcA()` says "... casting is added by the **compiler**" --- 2. `MyNode` extends `Node<Integer>`, so the `setData(T data)` method in `Node` is `setData(Integer data)`, which means that `setData(Integer data)` method in `MyNode` is an override. Logically speaking, from Java's perspective. But the JVM works a bit differently, so the compile needs to add a bridge method to "bridge the gap" between how Java sees the world and how the JVM actually runs the world.

Comment: 1. I understand that the compiler makes the _Dog_ cast, but according to what, he makes the cast? According to left side of assignemt statement? 2. Why do you say that it overrides the method. Does't it only inherits the method from _Node_ class? sorry but i can't understand why to method is "doubled" and not exist only once? If it is difficult to explain better that you already it's ok. I see that i have a huge gap in understanding the issue

Comment: @Eitanos30 1. According to the type the compiler has *inferred* for `T`, i.e. `Dog`. If you want to know how *type inference* works, read [Chapter 18. Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @Eitanos30 2. According to *Java generics*, the `MyNode.setData(Integer)` method is an override of the `Node.setData(T)`, because `T` is declared as `Integer` (`extends Node<Integer>`). That's Java. --- According to the *JVM*, the `MyNode.setData(Integer)` method is not an override of the `Node.setData(Object)` method, since a overriding method must have signature `setData(Object)`, so a `MyNode.setData(Object)` method is needed to "bridge the gap".

Answer (score -2):

There is no cast in the generic code at all. In Java object references are binary unchanged when a cast expression is evaluated. Any reference type is always just `object`. Everything else are guarantees from the compiler. So there is just no need for a cast in the generic code.

In fact a cast generates only some code like

```
if (!(obj instanceof desiredtype))
    throw new ClassCastException();
```

However, Java allows to cast from *untyped types* to generic types. This can result in bad types returned by functions. It is up to the caller to deal with this situations. The three callers knows their individual, expected type. So they can check for unexpected results (i.e cast) when needed.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The compiler *does* insert casts at the call sites of generic method. E.g., if a caller has a `List<String>`, the result of `get(int)` is implicitly cast to `String`, and a `ClassCastException` is thrown if the result is not a `String` (which can happen if warnings about type-safety are ignored). If that's not what you meant, please clarify your answer.

Comment: You are right, it could be misunderstood. But it is important that there is no guarantee about the casts at the caller site. There are some situations e.g. with Lambda expressions where no such cast is generated. For trivial cases like a generic return type the cast is performed, but not in the generic code like to OP assumed.